# I need help determining the difference between my code that I believe produces the same result as another, but won't be accepted

Tags: javascript, variables

I am stuck on how my code will not be accepted by freeCodeCamp's auto-grader. The objective was to create a function without any parameters that will generate a random number using `Math.random()`. Then we would have to multiply the randomly generated number by 10. After multiplying the randomly generated by 10, I would have to use `Math.floor()` to round it up or down.

Link to challenge: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/generate-random-whole-numbers-with-javascript

These are the objectives given to me, quoted directly from freeCodeCamp's challenge:

1.) **The result of randomWholeNum should be a whole number.**

2.) **You should use Math.random to generate a random number.**

3.) **You should have multiplied the result of Math.random by 10 to make it a number that is between zero and nine.**

4.) **You should use Math.floor to remove the decimal part of the number.**

Here is my code:

```
function randomWholeNum() {

  var x = Math.random();
  var z = x * 10;
  var y = Math.floor(z);
  return y;
}
```

As you can see, I used multiple variables to complete this task. `x` would generate the random number, `z` would store the random number multiplied by 10, `y` would round `z`, resulting in all objectives passed. However, when running the code, all objectives were ticked except for Number 3. I don't understand what went wrong, and after looking at the answer for the challenge,  which is:

```
function randomWholeNum() {
  // Only change code below this line.
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}
```

I don't understand why the code I wrote doesn't produce the same result of freeCodeCamp's own.

Comment: You are completely correct. I believe it is an issue with how it is graded and not your own code.

Comment: Sidenote: "*I would have to use Math.floor() to round it up or down.*" - `Math.floor()` always rounds down, hence its name. `Math.round()` rounds up *or* down, as required.